# Validating binary input in C++

Tags: c++, function, validation, recursion

Hi i'm attempting to validate a user input looking for an input of either 1 or 0. The string validating part seems to work fine but any integer based input has the console window accepting the input but not jumping over the if statement, returning the input (maxItems). Here is the code :

```
int RollingStats::GetOption() 
{
       int maxItems;

        std::cout << "Please enter either to store data individually (0) or as a range(1)" << std::endl;

        std::cin >> maxItems;

        if ((!(std::cin >> maxItems) && maxItems != 0) | (!(std::cin >> maxItems) && maxItems != 1))
        {
            std::cin.clear();

            std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');

            std::cout << "Please enter an input of either 0 or 1" << std::endl;

            GetOption();
        }
            return maxItems;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use logical OR (`||`) instead of bit-wise or (`|`) in your `if` condition check.

Comment: I see a d6 and I want to paint it black. -The Rolling Stats.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues in the code:

- Using `cin` thrice (once before `if` and twice in the `if` condition) would require the user to input thrice
- Using logical OR (`||`) instead of bit-wise or (`|`) in your `if` condition check.
- Not checking if the input is an integer

You can do something like this instead:

```
int RollingStats::GetOption()
{
    int maxItems;
    std::cout << "Please enter either to store data individually (0) or as a range(1)" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> maxItems;

    if(!std::cin.good() || maxItems != 0 && maxItems != 1)
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        std::cout << "Please enter an input of either 0 or 1" << std::endl;
        maxItems = GetOption();
    } 
    return maxItems;
}
```